# Replace font awesome icon with image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a page with some company adresses for car repairment shops in my area.

[Demosite](http://vouzalis.dk/stack.html)

I used a font-awesome icon with a blue car for each address. That icon I would like to change to a small 50x50px picture instead. I have tried to replace the icon with a normal `img src` tag, but the picture is going above the text then.

How is the best way to change this? At the moment I have around 30 addresses, so I shorten the HTML down to just 1 row.

The font-awesome icon is set with this CSS class:

`#content .card .block-1:before{
      content: "\f1b9";
}`

A jsfiddle can be [seen here](https://jsfiddle.net/grf0pu3m/).

**HTML:**

```
<section id="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block block-1">
            <h3 class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum 1</h3>
            <p class="card-text">
              Adress 1<br/>
              1234 Postcode<br/>
              Tlf: <a href="tel:+9012345678">+90 12 34 56 78</a><br/>
            </p>
            <a href="#" title="Vis vej" target="_blank">Show direction<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right ml-2"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block block-1">
            <h3 class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum 2</h3>
            <p class="card-text">
              Adress 2<br/>
              1234 Postcode<br/>
              Tlf: <a href="tel:+9012345678">+90 12 34 56 78</a><br/>
            </p>
            <a href="#" title="Vis vej" target="_blank">Show direction<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right ml-2"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block block-1">
            <h3 class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum 3</h3>
            <p class="card-text">
              Adress 3<br/>
              1234 Postcode<br/>
              Tlf: <a href="tel:+9012345678">+90 12 34 56 78</a><br/>
            </p>
            <a href="#" title="Vis vej" target="_blank">Show direction<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right ml-2"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a background image in CSS where the icon is:

```
#content .card .block-1:before {
    content: " ";
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/50/50);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the thing))

```
#content .card .block-1:before { 
     content:url('http://yourdomain.net/example.png');
     width: 50px;
     height: auto;
}
```